# Google Sheets Script how can i automate the /lastpost

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

how i can automate send last entry on google sheets to my telegram bot?
In this moment when i send, in telegram bot, the comand /lastpost, show the last entry.

```
function doPost(e) {
// recebe um sinal do bot
var update = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
// verifique o tipo de recebimento, precisamos apenas do tipo "message"
if (update.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
var msg = update.message;
var chatId = msg.chat.id;   
// verifica se a mensagem é um comando para o bot
if (msg.hasOwnProperty('entities') && msg.entities[0].type == 'bot_command') 
{    
// verifica o nome do comando - / lastpost
if (msg.text == '/lastpost') {    
// se todas as verificações forem aprovadas - execute o código abaixo
// abre o índice do nosso canal
var sheet =  
SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID').getSheets()[0]  
// recebe a última postagem
var lastpost = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1,  3).getValues()[0]
var message = ' <strong>'+lastpost[1] + '</strong> \n' + lastpost[2]        
// forma uma mensagem com ele
var payload = {
'method': 'sendMessage',
'chat_id': String(chatId),
'text': "" + message + "" ,
'parse_mode': 'HTML'
 }    
 var data = {
 "method": "post",
 "payload": payload 
 }    
 // e envie para o bot (substitua a API pela sua)
 var API_TOKEN = 'API_TOKEN'
 UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', data);
 }
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You say that you want to automatically send the last entry of Google Sheets to Telegram Bot and this is exactly what you are doing. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i receive in telegram the last entry only when i send the code "/lastpost" in telegram bot